# Triple Prime Proof

Tags: prime-numbers

**Note**: Someone else has posted this proof as a question; however, that post is largely inactive. I am interested in exploring this proof, but don't know how to "bump" someone's post, so I'm re-posting it here. If there is another way I should go about this, I'm happy to do so.
<https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988393/not-sure-about-how-to-prove-this-primal-triple>

For the integers $(x, y, z)$ such that $2x = 3y = 5z$

Show that $xyz=n900$.

Any help to get me moving in the right direction?

Comment: Providing a link to the post you are talking about would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a link to that question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988393/not-sure-about-how-to-prove-this-primal-triple I voted to close the other one, as it lack context.

Comment: I've updated the post to include the link, thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2, 3 and 5 are all prime and pairwise *relatively* prime:
$$2x=3y=5z\implies15\mid x,\ 10\mid y,\ 6\mid z$$
(This may be seen from prime factorisations.) Therefore
$$15\cdot10\cdot6\mid xyz$$
$$900\mid xyz$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
2x=3y = 5z
$$

If $2x = 3y$ then $2x$ is a multiple of $3$.

Since $2$ is prime and not a multiple of $3$, we must conclude $x$ is a multiple of $3$.

For the same reason, $x$ must be a multiple of $5$.

So $x = 3\cdot5\cdot j$ for some integer $j$.

Similarly, $y =2\cdot5\cdot k$ and $z = 2\cdot3\cdot \ell$.

So $xyz = (3\cdot5\cdot j)(2\cdot5\cdot k)(2\cdot 3\cdot\ell) = (2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3 \cdot5\cdot5)jk\ell = 900 jk\ell.$

Answer (score 0):

Denote 
$$2x=3y=5z=k$$

Then $x=\frac{k}{2}$ is an integer, thus $2|k$. Similarly $3|k$ and $5|k$.

As $2,3,5$ are pairwise relatively prime, it follows that their product, 30, divides $k$.

Thus, we can write $k=30n$.

Then 
$$2x=3y=5z=30n\\
x=15n \\
y=10n \\
z=6 n \\
xyz=900 n^3$$